# IObserver -- what should the observer do when IObserver.OnError is called

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observer-pattern

I'm using the `IObserver`/`IObservable` interfaces in a project of mine.

The `CommandReader` is an `IObservable` which continuously reads data from a stream and then passes it to its `CommandHandler` `IObserver`(s).

When the underlying stream is closed (e.g. connection dies) then I will notify the observers with the `IObserver.OnError(exception)` method

What should the observer do when it receives this notification? Should it release itself from the observable? Or is that the parent class' responsibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you generally should not implement your own `IObservable` and `IObserver` objects. Your question kind of hints at why. It is very difficult to get the underlying behaviour correct.

Now each call to `IObservable.Subscribe` returns an `IDisposable`. This is used if the caller of `Subscribe` wishes to unsubscribe from an observable before an `OnCompleted` or `OnError` is called. However, if an `OnCompleted` or `OnError`  is called then the `IDisposable` is automatically disposed of. So effectively Rx automatically cleans up after itself when an observable collection complete.

Each individual observer does not need to manage it's own subscription lifetime. The observer only needs to respond to the `OnCompleted`/`OnError` message.

In your code I would suggest that you think about changing your code slightly. I would expect a `CommandReaderPublisher` class with a `Subscribe` method might be more appropriate than a `CommandReader` class. Once an Rx stream completes it cannot continue to be used.

Also I wonder if calling `OnCompleted` would be better than `OnError(exception)` when the underlying stream closes. If an error occurs then that's fine, but if it closes then `ONCompleted` might be better.

Comment: +1 Dont implement the IObserver/IObservable interfaces. Use the Rx library. Observable.Create/Generate/etc are how you create an Observable sequence and the Subscribe extension methods are how you consumer an observable sequence. www.IntroToRx.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it's the job of the IObservable to remove observers from it's own subscription list. Likewise, if an IObserver has a list of IObservables, then the IObserver should manage that list.